# Adding a search field in html form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a basic Html form . I am trying to build a search bar that would highlight a label which matches that content . Here is my [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pathakrohit/ohmzuc3n/). The search is not perfect. For eg when trying to search keyword `First` it highlights all the labels that starts with `F`.

```js
$("#searchbox").keydown(function() {
        var content = $('#searchbox').val();
        if(content!== ""){
            if ($("label:contains('"+content+"')"))
            {
                $("label:contains('"+content+"')").addClass("highlight");
            } else {
                $("label:contains('"+content+"')").removeClass("highlight");
            }
        }
        else{
            $("label:contains('"+content+"')").removeClass("highlight");
        }
     });
```

```css
      .highlight{
            border: red;
            background-color: yellow;

        }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <br/>
  <input id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter your search term">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="first">First</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="second">Second</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="third">Third</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fourth">Fourth</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fifth">Fifth</label><input type="text"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I am new to JQuery and I know this is not a clean code. This is what I tried by referring other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through `label` elements on `keyup` and check if the `text` includes the value of the search field and based on that add or remove a class.

```js
$("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
  const content = $('#searchbox').val().toLowerCase();
  const labels = $('label');

  labels.each(function() {
    const check = $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(content)
    if (content.length && check) $(this).addClass('highlight')
    else $(this).removeClass('highlight')
  })
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br />
  <input id="searchbox" placeholder="Enter your search term">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="first">First</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="second">Second</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="third">Third</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fourth">Fourth</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="form-group"><label for="fifth">Fifth</label><input type="text"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```